# Tridion Solr with Load Balancer issue on cloud

Tags: 2013

Did anybody implement Solr master/slave configuration with load balancer on Solr cloud with Tridion? Looking for best practices around the same.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

When we are talking about the Solr Cloud, it essentially means an advancement in the Master-Slave configuration of the Solr. Usually, with SolrCloud, you should be implementing a ZooKeeper quorum instead of plain Master-Slave Configuration.

Below URL explains how to setup an external ZooKeeper:

[Setting Up an External ZooKeeper Ensemble](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble)

Below is a listing of an example setup of SolrCloud with Master-Slave replication in Load Balancer with ZooKeeper:

[Solr Cloud Master-Slave Replication](http://pulkitsinghal.blogspot.in/2011/09/multicore-master-slave-replication-in.html)

Further, you can get a basic idea and comparison of Master-Slave replication and ZooKeeper:

[Comparing Master-Slave with Zoo Keeper](https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/201298317-What-is-SolrCloud-And-how-does-it-compare-to-master-slave-)

Further, I did this for a client and this is not yet out in community; will try to push this in community later in this year.